# Erro ao carregar a library database do Codeiginiter

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache

Estou com o seguinte erro no codeginiter:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 135
>
> Backtrace:

Já fui até o php.ini e retirei os comentários do `extension=php_mysql.dll` , `extension=php_mysqli.dll` e o coloquei o caminho no `extension_dir = "C:/php/ext"`, alguém que já passou por isso sabe a solução?

***Obs: estou tentado hospedar no Apache porque no php cli funciona normalmente***

Comment: Se você tiver utilizando WampServer, XAMPP etc. Provavelmente estás alterando o `php.ini` incorreto. Crie um arquivo PHP e executo o código `<?php phpinfo();`. Lá mostrará o arquivo "correto".

Comment: @ValdeirPsr mas em que parte do phpinfo() sei que o apache está unsado?

Comment: basta pesquisar (Ctrl + F) por `php.ini`. O valor fica em `Loaded Configuration File`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr então achei o caminho porém ele aponta para o C:\Window mas lá não tem nenhum php.ini

Comment: Você utiliza algum software como WampServer ou XAMPP?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr então cara consegui resolver lá no httpd.conf na última linha eu coloquei o PhpIniDir + o caminho em que estava instalado o php junto com o php.ini. Mas vlw pela ajuda.

Comment: Responda à sua própria questão. Não deixe aberta. Atrapalha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `httpd.conf` na última linha eu coloquei o `PhpIniDir` + o caminho em que estava instalado o php.ini